# Testing Symfony2 session

Tags: php, session, symfony, testing, functional-testing

Here is the action in my controller code:

```
//DefaultController.php
public function resultsAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $data = $session->get('custom_data');
    var_dump($data);
    //...
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
//DefaultControllerTest.php
public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient(array(), array(
            'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'MySuperBrowser/1.0',
        ));
    $this->client->insulate();
    $this->client->followRedirects(true);
    $sessionMock = new MockFileSessionStorage();
    $this->session = new Session($sessionMock);
}

public function testAdslRisultati()
{
    $data = array(
        'key1' => 'val1',
        'key2' => 'val2' //etc...,
    );
    $this->session->set('custom_data', $data);
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/results');
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("text...")')->count() > 0);
}
```

When I execute the test, the value of $data in the controller is always empty. How can I save any data in session from test and retry it from controller?

```
//config_test.yml
framework:
test: ~
session:
    storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your can get the session storage from container in client

As example:

```
$this->client->getContainer()->get('session')->set('foo_bar', 'Bar');
```

**Attention:** The container in client used only for one request (`$client->request()`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I get this error:
RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/var/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Util/Printer.php" at line 172.

Comment: Somewhere used real mechanism sessions. Please see full code and your must disable really session.